# NoClassDefFoundError when using RestAssured with HttpClient

Tags: spring-boot, apache-httpclient-4.x, rest-assured

I'm trying to use RestAssured to test a Rest API.

I'm getting a `NoClassDefFoundError` when setting RestAssured.baseURI in my setup method.

I've checked and I have httpclient-4.5.6.jar. I've also tried reverting to old versions to no avail.

Error:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/http/client/HttpClient
    at io.restassured.config.HttpClientConfig.defaultHttpClientFactory(HttpClientConfig.java:264)
    at io.restassured.config.HttpClientConfig.<init>(HttpClientConfig.java:76)
    at io.restassured.config.RestAssuredConfig.<init>(RestAssuredConfig.java:41)
    at io.restassured.RestAssured.<clinit>(RestAssured.java:420)
```

Comment: Paste your complete rest assured code here along with the POM file

Comment: The problem is in import. Check your package imports on top of the class.